# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) when calling update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a method that is called every time the user signs in to my app using facebook or gplus, where I update all the user fields on each sign in.

```
   user = where(:email => email).first_or_create do |user|
      user.uid = uid
      user.email = email
      user.provider = provider
      user.save!
    end
    user.first_name = auth["first_name"]
    user.last_name = auth["last_name"]
    user.nickname = auth["first_name"]
    user.name = auth["name"]
    user.gender = auth["gender"]
    user.role = "user"
    user.latitude = 0
    user.longitude = 0
    user.update_attributes(user.attributes)
    user
```

but i get the following error everytime this method is called, in a similar note, I get this error even when I try updating a single attribute

```
user.upate_attributes(:token => token)
```

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

can't seem to figure out why

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just save the user instance

```
# ...
user.longitude = 0
user.save
```

or try this way

```
user.update_attributes(
  first_name: auth["first_name"],
  last_name: auth["last_name"],
  nickname: auth["first_name"],
  name: auth["name"],
  gender: auth["gender"],
  role: "user",
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0
)
```

Also, In your second command, there is a typo

```
user.upate_attributes(:token => token)
# Change to 
user.update_attributes(:token => token)
```

Comment: user.save gives me the same error, and so does the other way! :/

Comment: This error `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`  or something else

Comment: can you also please post the backtrace

Comment: Solved it, it was a stupid error!
So, basically I was using a facebook login, and had a secure password, wouldnt let me proceed until an encrypted password was provided. Removed that, it works as expected now!

Comment: oh... thats great